# Why are my SQL Server identity values being reused?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, identity, uniqueidentifier

I have a table that I am using to queue information before it is sent off to another system (Dynamics CRM). I write information to that queue and another service comes along and writes the data to CRM.

I used an identity value for the primary key and save this key with the information so I can track where it came from if anything goes wrong. After pulling the data out of the queue, I delete the record.

However, it looks like SQL Server is reusing keys on the identity field. Many ids are used only once, but many are used twice and quite a few have been used three times. Obviously this makes looking up a history by that id useless. Am I doing something wrong? I thought identity values should be unique and a table should not reuse them.

Here are the properties for the column, if that helps.

[image: Column Properties]

More properties on the primary key property:

[image]

Comment: Are you using `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: @Tocco That's a good question, I am using an integration service called "Scribe." All I do is check a checkbox that says "Delete Source Rows" I am not sure exactly what T-SQL it uses to perform that delete. If it is using a Truncate table, would that cause the keys to be reused?

Comment: Yes, `TRUNCATE TABLE` resets identity columns.  You must use `DELETE` to keep identity values from resetting.

Comment: By Chad "A `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement will clear the identity values ..."

Comment: @Jeff Davis, can you link that "Scribe"?

Comment: https://openmind.scribesoftware.com/forums

Comment: I changed the tag from [tag:sql-server-2008] to [tag:sql-server-2008-r2]. SQL Server 2008 <> SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identity values will be unique within the table as the moment it is needed.

The SQL engine has no knowledge of old identity values if you truncate the table.

If you want a value that will only ever be used once during the lifetime of a table you should consider a GUID or create a unique key based on identity + datetime.

Comment: In this case I can just stop deleting records. It's not really necessary, it was just cleaner. This describes the issue perfectly, however.

Comment: You should still figure out why Scribe is insisting on filling in the gaps you create when you delete rows, though. This is quite unintuitive behavior and I fail to see the point of re-using these meaningless ID values over time.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you're retrieving the identity (@@identity, etc.), but there are some scope-related limitations with the different approaches to this.

Here is a (limited, but fair) write-up on 3 methods for getting identity:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Answer (score 2):

IDENTITY on its own does not mean UNIQUE - it just means auto-increment from the current seed value by the increment value. It doesn't care if there is already such a value. If you also declare the column as unique (in situations like yours, this usually means marking it as the primary key), you will not get any of these duplicates, and you should find out quite quickly who is at fault because the application or the user will get constraint violation errors.

Other than [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx), there are other ways that IDENTITY values can be similarly violated:

[DBCC CHECKIDENT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) can be used to manually set the current seed value to anything the user wants.

[SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) can be used to manually override the next available value. Scribe may be doing this so that they don't have to care whether you've made a column an identity value or not, they can still override it with whatever they want.

You could run a server-side trace that would capture these events to find out if any of them are being called.

It's always useful to specify which version of SQL Server you're using, or at least tag the question with the minimum version you need to support, as the solution and behavior for SQL Server 2000, for example, can often be quite different than SQL Server 2008 R2. Just a helpful tip for future question.

Comment: OK. This is SQL Server 2008 R2. Also, it is set as a primary key. The column also says "Is Unique" | "Yes"

Comment: Then there is absolutely no way that table has two values that are the same. Unless you found a really big bug in SQL Server that nobody else in the world has ever discovered. Note that seeing the same value twice over time is not the same thing as seeing the same value twice at the same time.

Comment: Ok, your note describes perfectly what I am seeing. I am seeing the same value twice over time. Not the same value twice at the same time. I want the values to be unique forever, not just unique while they sit in the queue. That must be what I misunderstood about what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

A `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement will clear the identity values.  Identity values can also be specifically inserted by setting `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON`.

Without knowing much about how your system is designed, I would suggest making that identity column either a primary key (if appropriate) or a unique index.  Seeing what applications subsequently fail to update your database will show how and where the new identity columns are coming from.

However, as stated above if you are using `TRUNCATE TABLE` and simply exposing these identity columns elsewhere (preserving them in some other table for instance), then this is expected behavior.

If you are deleting all rows from the table and want to keep the identity from being reseeded, you have to instead use the `DELETE` command.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

Comment: I did some testing and had the service read and delete a few rows. It did not reset the identity (at least this time). The system has been running for a few months, and it looks like the identity has been reset 3 or 4 times, so whatever causes it, it doesn't happen very often.

Answer (score 0):

If you have related tables, the very first thing I would do is make sure that you have actually set up the PK/FK relationships. Many developers just assume the application will handle this and get into trouble when something like this happens. You cannot truncate the table if it has foreign keys whchi would prevent the reuse of the identities.

If there are multiple uses of the identity in the same table at the same time, the identity cannot by definintion be a PK unless it is part of a mulitple field PK. If you actually have this case, I suggest the best thing to do is to consult with  with Microsoft as someting entirely strinage has happened. If people are delting old ones and reusing them, that is a differnt story.

Apparently there is some process or person who has reset the values on the past for some unknown reason. You can use DDL triggers to record if someone changes the PK, drops Foreign key constraints etc. At least this way you can find what process is doing this.